# Голосовой поиск php

Tags: поиск, php, веб-программирование, плагин

Здравствуйте! Хотел создать сайт по голосовому запросу нахождение фраз,поэм,рассказов,поэзий.
Как использовать голосовой поиск? как добавить свой голос в  базу данных? Какие идеи по этому поводу?

Comment: [google speech api](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144535/) не подойдет?

Comment: По сравнению с любым приложением или фреймворком на php, с которым вы сталкивались, это задача прямо-таки необычайной величины, сродни созданию пароля из сетчатки глаза. Это не должно делаться на php в принципе из соображений скорости, и лучше всего взять какое-либо стороннее решение, потому что объем необходимых знаний для реализации преобразования голоса в слова может превышать пару десятков книг (я уж молчу про объем кода).

Answer (score 1):

Голос это колебания воздуха определенной частоты. Записать голос, разложить на спектр. Сохранять снимки определенных интервалов по ним проводить поиск.
Уровень программирования - высокий
Ссылки для ознакомления [link text](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150251/)

Comment: >колебания воздуха определенной частоты

Просто колебания воздуха, либо сумма колебаний разных частот, простите за педантичность.

Answer (score 0):

Средствами одного PHP не обойтись, это как минимум средствами HTML5 или Flash захватывать звук с микрофона, затем использовать к примеру приведенный выше Google Speech API или аналог (коих огромное количество, но главное ведь качество) и уже с распознанным текстом оперировать с БД

Самый простой и действенный вариант